# Django - Filter ForeignKey drop down menu in inline formsets

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

**models.py**

```
class Train(models.Model):
    pass

class City(models.Model):
    train = models.ForeignKey(Train)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Route(models.Model):
    train = models.ForeignKey(Train)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Travel(models.Model):
    train = models.ForeignKey(Train)
    current_city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name = 'current')
    through = models.ForeignKey(Route)
    next_city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name = 'next')
```

and I'm using inline formsets to create Travel instances related to a specific train with the following:

**views.py**

```
class TrainInfoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Train
    fields = []
    success_url = reverse_lazy('train-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(TrainInfoUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['travels'] = TravelFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['travels'] = TravelFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        travels = context['travels']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if travels.is_valid():
                travels.instance = self.object
                travels.save()
        return super(TrainInfoUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TrainForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Train

class CityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = City

class RouteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Route

class TravelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Travel

CityFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Train, City, form=CityForm, extra=1)

RouteFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Train, Route, form=RouteForm, extra=1)

TravelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Train, Travel, form=TravelForm, extra=1)
```

This gives me dropdown menu with all the cities and routes available but I would like to limit them to only the cities and routes related to that train, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Where is the code for `TravelFormSet` and forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this](https://dashdrum.com/blog/2010/08/django-custom-queryset-with-a-formset/) I managed to find a solution by defining a queryset in my views.py like so:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(TrainInfoUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    cities_query = City.objects.all().filter(train=self.object)
    routes_query = Route.objects.all().filter(train=self.object)
    if self.request.POST:
        data['travels'] = TravelFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        for form in data['travels']:
            form.fields['current_city'].queryset = cities_query
            form.fields['next_city'].queryset = cities_query
            form.fields['through'].queryset = routes_query
    else:
        data['travels'] = TravelFormSet(instance=self.object)
        for form in data['travels']:
            form.fields['current_city'].queryset = cities_query
            form.fields['next_city'].queryset = cities_query
            form.fields['through'].queryset = routes_query
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formfield_callback` argument to `inlineformset_factory` to customize the queryset. The inline documentation the source code says this about the `formfield_callback` argument:

> `formfield_callback` is a callable that takes a model field and
>   returns
>       a form field.

For your case the solution would be:

```
def custom_form_field_callback(field, **kwargs):
    cities_query = City.objects.filter(filter_field=filter_value)
    if field.name == "city":
         return City(queryset= cities_query) 
    else:
         return field.formfield(**kwargs)

CityFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Train, City, formfield_callback=custom_form_field_callback)
```

**Note**: If you are not customizing the ModelForm then you don't need to pass the `form=CityForm` argument to `inlineformset_factory`